# Ubuntu: background task does not want to get back in the foreground

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I have a java program running on my linux server, the jar has been startet with "&" and is now running in the background, by using htop I can see it too. Now, I tried jobs or fg to get the task back to the foreground, without success. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
erdo@localhost:~$ jobs -l
erdo@localhost:~$ fg 45502
-bash: fg: 45502: no such job
```

Comment: You need a job or process to be stopped before you can use `fg` to resume it in the foreground.  If it is not already stopped, you should be able to stop it with `kill -STOP`.

Comment: However, the process also needs to be in the same session, and have the same controlling terminal.  Roughly speaking, that means it needs to have been started from the same terminal where you issue the `fg` command, and maybe even from the same instance of the shell.

Answer (score 1):

type ***jobs***

You will get list of all your background processes

```
[1]  Stopped notepadQQ
[2]  Stopped bash
[3]  Stopped /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-1.8.0/bin/java -version
[4]  Running /process/you/neeed
```

use background process index number with fg command to bring it back to the foreground

```
fg %4
```

*Edit::*

This method only works **if you are using the same shell**. Be aware that **you cannot take over a process that was started in a different shell**.

If you want to get access to your processes from different terminal you should use **virtual terminal manager** like *tmux* or *screen*

Comment: by typing jobs or jobs -l I do not get any response

Comment: Are you using the same shell? job shows background commands belonging to the same shell only

Comment: Indeed, no, Im not using the same shell .. is there a way to get a task back in foreground anyway?

Comment: **you cannot take over a process that was started in a different shell**

if you want to get access to your processes from different terminal you should use **virtual terminal manager** like tmux or screen and run your backgroun process from virtual terminal